# How can i display lat and lng coordinates inside a fieldset(<input type="text" name="lng" id="lng" placeholder="Longitude">)?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to display my **lat** and **lng** coordinates automatically inside an input **textfield** shown in my **infoWindow** when i click a place on my map...so i can save accurate marker coordinates of user in my database...

This is from 2 different div classes. is this even possible?

```html
<fieldset>
    <input type="text" name="userId" id="userId" placeholder="Your userID">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" placeholder="firsName">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <input type="text"  name="lastName" id="lastName" placeholder="lastName">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <input type="number" name="age" id="age" placeholder="age">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <input type="text"  name="symptom" id="symptom" placeholder="Symptoms">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <input type="text"   name="lat" id="lat" placeholder="Latitude">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <input type="text"   name="lng" id="lng" placeholder="Longitude">
  </fieldset>
```

```js
function initialize() {
        var myLatlng = {lat:14.5907332, lng:120.9809674};
        

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
         {zoom: 4, center: myLatlng});

        // Create the initial InfoWindow.
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
            {content: 'Click the map to get Lat/Lng!', position: myLatlng});
        infoWindow.open(map);

        // Configure the click listener.
        map.addListener('click', function(mapsMouseEvent) {
          // Close the current InfoWindow.
          infoWindow.close();

          // Create a new InfoWindow.
          infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({position: mapsMouseEvent.latLng});
          infoWindow.setContent(mapsMouseEvent.latLng.toString());
          infoWindow.open(map);
        });
```

This [my web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XboZr.png)

I have tried the manual way of clicking the map and copying the coordinates and putting them
on my textfield then saving to my database, but it's too time consuming....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a setter method, and call it in click event after setting the content of the info window.

```
function setLatLng(mapsMouseEvent){
   let latInputBox = document.getElementById("lat");
   let lngInputBox = document.getElementById("lng"); 
   latInputBox.value = mapsMouseEvent.latlng.lat();
   lngInputBox.value = mapsMouseEvent.latlng.lng();
   
}
```

call this method from the click event function:

```
     // Configure the click listener.
      map.addListener('click', function(mapsMouseEvent) {
       // Close the current InfoWindow.
       infoWindow.close();

      // Create a new InfoWindow.
      infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({position: mapsMouseEvent.latLng});
      infoWindow.setContent(mapsMouseEvent.latLng.toString());
      infoWindow.open(map);
      setLatLng(mapsMouseEvent);// call to set in input fields
    });
```

Comment: Now i can't save it to firebase because it has ** () ** on my coordinates. i had to manually delete  **()** then it will save to firebase. Any chance i can remove **()** whenever i click the map?

Comment: You can use mapsMouseEvent.latLng.lat() and mapsMouseEvent.latLng.lng() function to get individual and pass it to function either way: I am updating the code for future.